# Asp net core mvc configuration appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm developing an MVC app and i want to manage settings.
I've read this guide:
[LINK](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)

and this microsoft's guide:
[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

I'm able to get the values from json to my controller correctly,
but now i'm searching how to **WRITE setting TO JSON from controller**.

Do I have to implement an IConfigureOptions ?
Eventually, what should be the best alternative way to save settings? 
Do I have to save it in DB using EntityFramework?

The CustomSetting JSON paragraph is the following:

```
"CustomSettings": {
  "MinimumDouble": 0,
  "MaximumDouble": 25000,
  "MyClassFirst": {
    "LimitDouble": 0,
    "Percent": 15
  }
}
```

And the c# class:

```
public class CustomSettings
{
    public double MinimumDouble { get; set; } = 0;
    public double MaximumDouble { get; set; } = 2000;
    public MyClass MyClassFirst { get; set; } = 2000;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public double LimitDouble { get; set; } = 0;
    public double Percent { get; set; } = 15;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to write data to your appsettings.json file, as these values should be fixed for the application. What kind of data would you like to save that changes during application runtime? I think it is best to create a new file or write it to a db.

Comment: OK thank you for your suggestion. I have to write some basic settings, for example the limit of a double that a user can insert, but i want the administrator to be able to change this value as he/she wants (on a db they would be written in a single row)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

As suggested by Wouter, I created a custom class that can read/save settings in a Json file (not appsettings.json). 
Using simply the Newtonsoft Json library (and deserialize function).
Works well and I don't need to make a call to DB.

If there is a better way, I keep on listening :)